# Why did adding another if statement to the while loop break me out of the loop prematurely?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I'm following a tutorial on while loops that is using a  number guessing game as an example.  The loop is set to break after three incorrect tries and prints "You lose".  I wanted to add another if statement to print after each incorrect guess (Try again), but when I did the loop breaks after the first guess instead of running through all three attempts. Prior to adding the second if statement the program ran through the entire loop correctly.

```
secret_number = 6
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = int(input('Guess the secret number! '))
    guess_count += 1
    if guess == secret_number:
        print('...You Won!')
    if guess != secret_number:
        print('Nope. Try again!')
        break
else:
    print('...Sorry, you failed.'
```

As I understand it, the break ignores the if statements and only follows the parameters set by the while command. I don't understand why adding an additional if statement kills the loop after the first attempt.

Comment: You are using `break` in the wrong place then. You want to `break` out when winning, not when asking to try again.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm beginning to appreciate the literalness of programming.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misplaced `break`. You should break from loop when there's a correct guess and retry looping on a wrong guess.

```
secret_number = 6
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = int(input('Guess the secret number! '))
    guess_count += 1
    if guess == secret_number:
        print('...You Won!')
        break
    if guess != secret_number and guess_count != guess_limit:
        print('Nope. Try again!')
else:
    print('...Sorry, you failed.')
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved it.  Once you said that I misplaced break, I switched the if statement order, which ended up working.  I'm going to try your solution next.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> The break statement, like in C, breaks out of the innermost enclosing for or while loop.
>   https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

With:

```
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    ....
    if guess != secret_number:
            print('Nope. Try again!')
            break
```

You're essentially saying: exit the while loop when the guess is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I wasn't thinking that break applies only to the if statement before it.